# 'A scientific thing is not scientific'

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

1. This scientific thing is not scientific.
2. This scientific thing doesn't have a state of being scientific. (This scientific thing isn't without a state of being scientific).

Do verbs of these sentences make a state of being scientific negative?

I'm confused because even though a subject means something because of a verb the subject becomes a negative as in 'this scientific thing doesn't exist.' So does the sentences above have the verbs that negate a state of being scientific of the subjects?

Context

A: Earth is flat

B: This is not scientific

I want to express the opinion of B with the sentences above.

It's not metaphorical but literal.

Similar example:
'a red ball is not red'
'blue sky has no blueness'
'there's an unfortunate fortunate man'

Comment: Hi, your question at present isn't suitable for this site. It needs some context and more information about what you don't understand. You  could explain what you *want* to say, why you formulated these two sentences differently, and what aspect of the language you don't understand.

Comment: *"This "scientific" claim is not scientific at all!"* one might say after watching one of Trump's press conferences...

Comment: Welcome to ELL @customer'salwaysright, please do not be discouraged by the downvotes. Someone else and I have counteracted the downvotes. :)

Comment: If someone says to me that "Earth is flat", I would simply respond them by saying "That is definitely false. Scientific fact and reasoning says so."

Comment: I insist to say the two sentences above.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I would query **false (scientific) fact** on the basis that if it is false, it is not a fact, merely a hypothesis/allegation/assumption/assertion or whatever. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fact    https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fact

Comment: I've looked at this and tried to understand the question.  It doesn't make sense...  The verbs don't make it negative.  the word "not" makes it negative.  But the examples are so non-sensical that very little can be said.  I don't know what your real problem of English Learning is, and I've voted to block further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Without some context, one cannot be sure of an answer.

If you are considering writing these sentences, please describe the context. If you read such a sentence and wonder what it means, we need more of the text in which it is embedded.

Guessing on the context, I would construe the first as being sarcasm meaning

> This purportedly scientific thing is not scientific in any respect.

And yes, you can deny the existence of the subject.

> The unicorn of medieval conception corresponds to nothing known to biology though it may have had its origin in reports by travelers of the rhinoceros.

Comment: I mean, can a verb make not a whole sense but some sense of a subject negative?

Comment: @customer'salwaysright I am sorry, but that question makes no sense to me at all. I told you (a) we need context, and (b) what is the natural interpretation of your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but:

*X is not Y*
*X doesn't have a state of being Y*

The second sentence there is awkwardly phrased, but it *means* the same as the first one. Those are both describing *X* as not having state *Y*, or having a state of *negative Y*.

*This coffee is not hot*

*Hot* is an attribute, *this coffee* does not have that attribute. Its state **does not include** *hot*, and implies that it has some attribute from a set that excludes *hot*, like *cold*, *warm*, *room-temperature* etc.

---

That's the grammar at work here. Your examples are specifically this format:

*X is not X*

If you're asking "what does it mean to say that a thing isn't that thing", then really you're getting into philsophy! We can't answer that for you, or tell you what people will think if you say a sentence like that.

If you want to say that "the thing described as *X* isn't *X* at all" then Andrew Tobilko's comment is a good example of how to handle it, with quotes:

*The "scientific" thing is not scientific*

The quotes act like reported speech - *someone* has called this thing "scientific", but your opinion is that isn't not scientific at all. Without the quotes you're the one describing the thing as scientific, and then saying that it's not scientific - that's where the contradiction and confusion comes in.

You can say that kind of thing rhetorically, using the contradiction to describe a change of opinion of perspective (e.g. "my favourite show is the worst" after something bad happens on it, and you no longer like it) but it still might confuse people. It's how you express it really, and the quotes can help (you can "say" them by stressing the word, or say *so-called "scientific"* instead).

Sorry if that was confusing, I feel like your question is getting into some pretty deep themes though! Hopefully that helps you to understand whatever you're thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

"This scientific thing is not scientific." The statement as written contradicts itself, or at least appears to. It could be a paradox or a riddle.

You say you're talking about flat earth theories. Unless you're trying to create a paradox, I just wouldn't say it this way. You might say, "Supporters claim that this is a scientific theory, but it isn't really scientific."

Exactly how you word it depends on precisely how you define "science". There are plenty of theories that have been proposed at one time or another that I would not hesitate to describe as "scientific theories", but which ultimately turned out to not be true. The Bohr atom, for example.  Or phlogistan. I certainly would not say that "scientific" is a synonym for "true". There are lots of things that are true that cannot be studied by science. Like, "Caesar Augustus was emperor or Rome." There's no scientific experiment you could do to prove that true or false. It's not a scientific question. It's a historical question. And of course statements like "Beethoven's Fifth Symphony is a great work of music" ... how would one even begin to study such a question scientifically? On the other hand, let me go back to the Bohr atom. Niels Bohr proposed a theory about the nature of the atom. It was an attempt to describe a physical phenomenon. He and others proposed experiments to test it. Ultimately it was proven to be wrong. But I have never heard any scientist describe it as "unscientific" or "not scientific".

So is a flat earth theory "scientific"? Hmm. It's a theory about a physical phenomenon: the shape of the Earth. It can be tested by experiment. There are numerous experiments that have been done that conflict with the flat earth theory and confirm the round earth theory. So I'd say that it is a scientific theory that has been proven false, not that it is not scientific.

It might well be true that many proponents of the flat earth theory are unscientific. That is, that they ignore the experimental evidence and cling to their theory despite the evidence.

Anyway, all that said, a statement like "This scientific thing is not scientific" could be a paradox used to discuss the question of what we mean by "science". If you use a different definition for "science" the first time the word is used than for the second, the sentence could be true. Like if you shift between defining "science" as "statements about the physical universe", "statements that are subject to experimental testing and verification", "statements that are true", heck, often the media use "science" to mean "statements made in press releases from organizations that have the word 'science' in their name".

Answer (score -1):

A koan for your enlightenment:

> This colorless zebra is not colorless.

The word *scientific* does not go very well with *thing*.  It sounds odd.

---

Your example sentence was bad.  Let's try to get this fixed.

1. These "parallel" lines are not parallel.
2. These "parallel" lines are not in the state of being parallel.

**Do the verbs in these sentences make the state of being parallel negative?**

Yes, but the lines were not parallel to begin with.